# How to get a count of groups that user has joined?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I have used OG module to implement the Groups functionality. I want to get:

1. Count of all groups that are there on the website
2. Count of groups that a user has joined

How can I do this?

Note:
My preference would be to use an existing function (if there is any).

Answer (score 1):

To get Count of all groups....

```
$groups = og_get_all_group($group_type = 'node');
$count = count($groups);
```

To get User Groups Count

```
$user_groups = og_get_groups_by_user();
$user_count = count($user_groups);
```